# What "channel1 <- <-channel2" does?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

In Concurrency Go Patterns (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs) there is an example of code that looks like:

```
func fanIn(in1 <-chan string) <-chan string {
    c:=make(chan string)
    go func() { 
        for {
            c <- <-in1 
        } 
    }() 
    return c
}
```

For me this looks very strange `c <- <-in1`. What does it mean?

Comment: You `fanIn` function does not compile. Maybe you should edit your post. Don't forget to add `in2`, If you are not using it you should not declare it. Maybe you could check the video again.

Comment: @apxp Fixed return value

Answer (score 0):

The `c <- <-in1` stands for:

```
in1Val := <-in1 // read from channel in1
c <- in1Val // write the value from in1 channel to `c` channel
```

If you write such kind of code first time - use more this detailed code to understand what happens better.